# Cannot GET image from Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, static

I am uploading images from my angular app into Node JS. The images are located in 'uploads' folder in my Node JS project. Here is the directory structure of my Node JS project.

```
var/ 
    - www/
        - html/
            - project/
                -   uploads/
                -   node_modules/
                -   config/
                -   src/
                -   server.js
```

I am using express.static method for defining the uploads directory as static like below:

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
```

When, I am trying to access the images in the uploads directory with the url - https://www.projectname.com/uploads/download.png. But the images are not showing up in the browser. I am getting the error "Cannot GET /api/uploads/download.png".

Here is my server.js code..

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dotEnv = require("dotenv");
const dbConn = require("./config/db.config");
var cors = require('cors');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const md5 = require('md5');

dotEnv.config();

//Create express app
const app = express();

//User CORS for cors policy
app.use(cors())

// Allowing X-domain request
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control");

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.send(200);
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);

//Parse requests of content-type
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//define roots
app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hello Welcome to SKD ISP");
});

// Require employee routes
const employeeRoutes = require("./src/routes/employee.routes");

// using as middleware
app.use('/api/v1/employees', employeeRoutes)


const path = require('path');

// Function to serve all static files
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))

//Listen for requests
app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is up and running");  
})
```

Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: you are requesting this address: `https://www.projectname.com/uploads/download.png.` but server returns this error!? `Cannot GET /api/uploads/download.png` where is /api ?

Comment: @sina.ce, I am calling the image using URL "https://www.projectname.com/uploads/download.png" and I am getting this error "Cannot GET /api/uploads/download.png". I am really confused where is that "api" coming from...

Comment: something redirecting the address to wrong path, do you have some router or NGINX in between ?

Comment: @sina.ce, I hope we have NGINX in between. My  network team is looking after that

Comment: in meantime please paste your middleware initialization and update your post so I can see that too

Comment: @sina.ce, I have added my server.js code here

Comment: Move `app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))` to the first part of the initialization of middlewares, is it fix now?

Comment: @sina.ce No luck..

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you have not defined this route, try this: [problem resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Wll.png)

```
app.get('/uploads/:filename', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/uploads/' + req.params.filename));
});
```